# ListBox with html element

Tags: html, .net, winforms, listbox, webbrowser-control

Can anyone offer me some advice? I currently have a listbox I am using, in the listbox there is a list of images from any website. they are grabbed from the website via this method

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
        imagestxt.Items.Add(imagestxt.Text & CurElement.GetAttribute("src") & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I then use the picture control method to get the image and display it.

```
pic1.Image = New Bitmap(New MemoryStream(New WebClient().DownloadData(imagestxtimagestxt.SelectedItem.ToString))).SelectedItem.ToString)))
```

This method pulls the images and title from the HTML.

```
Private Function StrHTML12() As Boolean
    Dim htmlDocument As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each element As HtmlElement In htmlDocument.All
        ListBox1.Items.Add(element.TagName)
        If element.TagName.ToUpper = "IMG" Then
            imgtags.Items.Add(element.OuterHtml.ToString)
        End If
        If element.TagName.ToUpper = "TITLE" Then
            titletags.Items.Add(element.OuterHtml.ToString)
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This is a counting method to count how many empty `alt=""` or empty `img alt=''` there are on the page.

Basically what i am looking to do is;

Have a program that can check the image, look at the `alt=''` or `img alt=''` if on the website the dev hasn't put anything in the alt tag i want the image to show in a picture box and i want the alt tag either next to it or underneith it or something. but i have no idea how.

```
counter = InStr(counter + 1, strHTML, "<img alt=''")
counter = InStr(counter + 1, strHTML, "alt=''")
counter = InStr(counter + 1, strHTML, "alt=""")
```

The above seems really slow and messy. is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Can't you just use `HtmlElement.GetAttribute("alt")`? You could do the same as your first code example pretty much

Comment: what would be the benefit of that?

Comment: Instead of using string functions you could loop through the Dom nodes checking to see if `alt` exists or has an empty value. Might need to clarify your question, as I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Please could you describe what you are trying to achieve, the end result. (add it to the bottom of your question)

Comment: the end goal is to find out how many empty ALT tags there are within a given HTML document. those tags need to be found, the src of the image displayed in datagridview control and counted so that feedback can be given via a report that will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have VB installed so I have not been able to test the code. I'm also not familiar with the datagridview component so have not attempted to integrate my code with it.

The code below should get you the `title` of the page, and loop through all the `img` tags that do not have (or have empty) `alt-text`

`HtmlElement.GetAttribute(sAttr)` returns the value of the attribute or an empty string.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim Title As String
    Dim ImSrc As String
    Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    // This line might need to be adjusted, see below
    Title = PageElements.GetElementsByTagName("title")(0).InnerText

    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
        If CurElement.GetAttribute("alt") = "" Then
             // CurElement does not have alt-text
             ImSrc = CurElement.GetAttribute("src") // This Image has no Alt Text
        Else
             // CurElement has alt-text
        End If
    Next
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

The line that gets the title might need to be changed as I'm unsure how collections can be accessed. You want the first (hopefully only) element returned from the `GetElementsByTagName` function.